# AWS kinesis Signaling channel: record videos to aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, signaling

I have a specific requirement. I need to record my webcam from my web browser. I can stream my webcam using an AWS Kinesis Signaling channel. Therefore, I need to know if the streamed video can be recorded and stored in AWS S3 as an MP4 file. Is this possible, and what services are required for tasks like video processing and transcoding?